# How do i use reconfigure in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

i have two Ext.grid.GridPanel but i have reconfigure from one to another.

How do i use reconfigure in Extjs .

```
Ext.reg('printsuppliers1', supplierlist1.Grid);
Ext.reg('printsuppliers2', supplierlist2.Grid);
```

here supplierlist1 has an actionlistner added say 'click' so when this actionlistener is invoked i want to reconfigure   supplierlist2.Grid ,can any body help me on this please ??

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem using `Ext.grid.GridPanel.reconfigure( Ext.data.Store store, Ext.grid.ColumnModel colModel )`? You have to provide a new store and a new column model (or just use the reference to the old column model).

What have you tried and what do you want to achieve (that's not quite clear reading your question)?

Comment: i guess he meant he have 2 grids, and wants to copy data from first to second one